# jquery post request response is a view from my index controller but i am not directing it there. I have custom routes

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter, post

I am using the most recent version of codeigniter here.

What i get back from this post request is my view. I am flummoxed.

My routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "veebn";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(:any)'] = "veebn/boshh/$1";
```

My post request:

```
$.post( "veebn/create_url", { weburl: weburl, width: width, height: height, dee: dee })
          .done(function( data ) {
             u = data;
             //alert(u);
    });
```

My controller:

```
public function create_url()
    {
        if($_POST['weburl'])
        {
            $u = $_POST['weburl'];
        }
        else
        {
            $width = NULL;
        }
        if($_POST['width'])
        {
            $width = $_POST['width'];
        }
        else
        {
            $width = NULL;
        }
        if($_POST['height'])
        {
            $height = $_POST['height'];
        }
        else
        {
            $width = NULL;
        }

        $deet = $_POST['dee'];
        //create new img
        echo $this->Img_model->get_url($u, $width, $height).$deet; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to isset() your if else statement.

sample

```
if(isset($_POST['weburl']))
```